# Expectation value of a convolution of probability densities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Assume we have a PDF, when we now calculate the convolution of this PDF with itself, what do we get in the end?

For Gaussian PDFs it's clear, we will have again an Gaussian but with $E[X]=2E[X_i]$. But how does this look for general PDFs? Is there any general information?

Best

Comment: think on this: if you convolve the PDF's, what is the operation you are doing over the random variables?

Comment: how do you conclude that for Gaussians $E[X] = 2E[X_i]$?

Comment: I meant: Two same gaussian distributions so E[X+X]=2E[X].

Comment: That's why I did my first comment. Why $X+X$? Because your are convolving the PDF's, no matter what the PDF is, and $E[X+X] = 2E[X]$ holds for any PDF.

Comment: Thanks! :-) then something must be wrong in my calculation or code...